# How to get a document containing order details

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, orders, magento-1.6, json

How do I get a document for a specific order in Magento (1.x) and (2.x) if possible please.

```
{
    "id": 100,
    "customer_id": 10,
    "date_created": "Wed, 14 Nov 2012 19:26:23 +0000",
    "date_modified": "Wed, 14 Nov 2012 19:26:23 +0000",
    "date_shipped": "",
    "status": "New",
    "subtotal_ex_tax": "99.0000",
    "subtotal_inc_tax": "99.0000",
    "subtotal_tax": "0.0000",
    "base_shipping_cost": "0.0000",
    "shipping_cost_ex_tax": "0.0000",
    "shipping_cost_inc_tax": "0.0000",
    "shipping_cost_tax": "0.0000",
    "shipping_cost_tax_class_id": 2,
    "base_handling_cost": "0.0000",
    "handling_cost_ex_tax": "0.0000",
    "handling_cost_inc_tax": "0.0000",
    "handling_cost_tax": "0.0000",
    "handling_cost_tax_class_id": 2,
    "base_wrapping_cost": "0.0000",
    "wrapping_cost_ex_tax": "0.0000",
    "wrapping_cost_inc_tax": "0.0000",
    "wrapping_cost_tax": "0.0000",
    "wrapping_cost_tax_class_id": 3,
    "total_ex_tax": "99.0000",
    "total_inc_tax": "99.0000",
    "total_tax": "0.0000",
    "items_total": 1,
    "items_shipped": 0,
    "payment_method": "cash",
    "payment_provider_id": null,
    "payment_status": "",
    "refunded_amount": "0.0000",
    "order_is_digital": false,
    "store_credit_amount": "0.0000",
    "gift_certificate_amount": "0.0000",
    "ip_address": "50.58.18.2",
    "geoip_country": "",
    "geoip_country_iso2": "",
    "currency_id": 1,
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "currency_exchange_rate": "1.0000000000",
    "default_currency_id": 1,
    "default_currency_code": "USD",
    "staff_notes": "",
    "customer_message": "",
    "discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "coupon_discount": "0.0000",
    "shipping_address_count": 1,
    "is_deleted": false,
    "billing_address": {
      "first_name": "Martin",
      "last_name": "Sheen",
      "company": "",
      "street_1": "12345 Fake Street",
      "street_2": "",
      "city": "Austin",
      "state": "Texas",
      "zip": "12345",
      "country": "United States",
      "country_iso2": "US",
      "phone": "",
      "email": "elsie@example.com"
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 16,
            "order_id": 115,
            "product_id": 111,
            "order_address_id": 16,
            "name": "Some Product",
            "sku": "",
            "price": "33.0000",
            "qty": 3,
        }
    ],
    "shipping_addresses": [
        {
          "first_name": "Martin",
          "last_name": "Sheen",
          "company": "",
          "street_1": "12345 Fake Street",
          "street_2": "",
          "city": "Austin",
          "state": "Texas",
          "zip": "12345",
          "country": "United States",
          "country_iso2": "US",
          "phone": "",
          "email": "elsie@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "coupons": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "coupon_id": 1,
          "order_id": 115,
          "code": "557D2DEA0CCAFA1",
          "amount": "5.0000",
          "type": 1,
          "discount": "4.6600"
        }
    ]
  }
```

I accept Magento probably doesn't spit documents like this out by default, and that some work will be needed to create such a structure, but I have no idea what the field names are or would be (not all fields essential, just shipping & billing address, customer details, status, totals and sub-totals, items, discounts & coupons).

If anything is not available from the above-abbreviated list, please let me know. Also how to say an order is shipping in Magento, and where to add tracking numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Magento doesn't support some of the things the API I was trying to shape it around does, but here is the initial code I came up with.

```
$_status = $_REQUEST['status'];

if(!file_exists('app/Mage.php')) {
    die("This must live within a valid Magento Installation\n");
}

require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', $_status)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'asc');

$orders = [];
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $orderData = [];

    $billing_address = $order->getBillingAddress();
    $shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
    $customer = $order->getCustomer();

    $orderData['id'] = $order->getId();
    $orderData['billing_address'] = getAddressData($billing_address);
    $orderData['shipping_address'] = getAddressData($shipping_address);

    $orderData['discount_amount'] = $order->getDiscountAmount();
    $orderData['subtotal_ex_tax'] = $order->getSubtotal();
    $orderData['shipping_cost_tax'] = $order->getTaxAmount();

    $orderData['currency_code'] = $order->getOrderCurrencyCode();
    $orderData['shipping_cost_inc_tax'] = $shipping_address->getShippingInclTax();
    // Guess at handling
    $orderData['handling_cost_inc_tax'] = $order->getGrandTotal()-$shipping_address->getShippingInclTax()-$order->getSubtotal();
    $orderDatap'payment_provider_id'] = $order->getPayment()->getMethod()->getCode();

    $orderData['products'] = [];
    foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $orderData['products'][] = [
            'sku' => $item->getSku(),
            'price_ex_tax' => $item->getPrice(),
            'quantity' => $item->getQuantity()
        ]
    }
    $orders[] = $orderData;
}

die(json_encode($orders, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

function getAddressData($obj) {
    $out = [];
    $out['first_name'] = $obj->getData('firstname');
    $out['last_name'] = $obj->getData('lastname');
    $out['street_1'] = $obj->getStreet(1);
    $out['street_2'] = $obj->getStreet(2);
    $out['phone'] = $obj->getTelephone();
    $out['zip'] = $obj->getPostcode();
    $out['city'] = $obj->getData('city');
    $out['state'] = $obj->getData('region');

    $out['country_iso2'] = $obj->getCountryModel()->getIso2Code();
    $out['email'] = $obj->getEmail();
    return $out;
}
```

I'll still need to heavily refactor & test the code, as well as find the differences between Magento1.x and 2.x. If you're wondering where I got this information from I had to look at the source code.